# Integral of Function of Two Variables Over Volume

Tags: integration

In my book, it asks me to take the integral of a scalar valued function of two variables over a volume domain.
My question is, what does it even mean to do this?
Is there any geometric representation of it?
I have only heard of taking the integral of function of two variables over area domain, and integral of function of three variables over volume.

Comment: Can you point to a particular example? Something like $\int\int\int_B x^2+y^2 dxdydz$ where $B$ is a ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$???

Comment: Exactly what I meant (integrals like those).

Comment: But ... then I don't understand what is worrying you. You can have a function "of two variables" $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$, but, written that way, it is obvious that it is actually a function of three variables. The fact that $z$ is not in the right-hand side just means that the function is *constant in $z$*, i.e. takes the same value for given $x,y$, no matter what the $z$ is.

Comment: However, the function that my book gives to integrate over a cylinder volume if f(x,y) = 2*sqrt(1+ x^2 + y^2).

Comment: (Cont'd) That makes it easier to integrate, because the integral of a constant is easy to calculate. For example, in the example above you can split it as $\int\int_D(x^2+y^2)\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dz\right)dxdy=\int\int_D 2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$ where $D$ is the disk $x^2+y^2\le 1$

Comment: Is there a way you can provide me with a geometric interpretation of integrating a two variable function over a volume domain? For example, integrating a two variable function over an area domain on xy-plane gives volume under the graph.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know... I have always seen them as functions of three variables (as noted in my comment before) - just as a special sort of functions where the third variable is not "used"... If you take the intuition for the triple integral over the volume (it gives the "mass" of the object; the function under integral is "density"), you can now try to imagine the object where the density does not depend on "height", e.g. a cylinder which, however inhomogenous, has all circular "layers" built the same. (E.g. it can become denser nearer the axis, but not e.g. on the top or bottom)